# Update variable data with the help of object key on window resize

Tags: javascript, slider

Recently I am trying to create slider like swiperjs.
Here is my code

```
let config = {
    perItem: 4,
    breakpoints: {
        992: {
            perItem: 3
        }
        768: {
            perItem: 2
        }
    }
}
let perItem = config.perItem
```

But I stuck in breakpoints. I wanna update perItem according to breakpoints.
how to achieve this in pure javascript.

Comment: *"I wanna update perItem according to breakpoints"* how would you like to do this? Based on what criteria?

Comment: with resize eventlistener.

Comment: Can you give an example of updating `perItem`, i.e. how should it look after getting updated?

Comment: Well here the initial `perItem` value is 4. when client resize the window javascript will get the `innerWith` and conditionally update `perItem` value. For example if `innerWidth` is less then 992 then `perItem = 3` if `innerWidth` is less then 768 then `perItem = 2` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after few experiment I avail to solve the problem.
Here is the solution

html

```
<div id="perItem">Initial perItem is 4</div>
```

js

```
let config = {
    perItem: 4,
    breakpoints: {
        992: {
            perItem: 3
        },
        768: {
            perItem: 2
        }
    }
}
let perItem = config.perItem

window.addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
  let array = []
  for (const width in config.breakpoints) {
    if (window.innerWidth < parseFloat(width)) {
      array.push(width) // store widths into array
      perItem = Math.floor(config.breakpoints[array[0]].perItem)
    } else {
      perItem = Math.floor(config.perItem)
    }
  }
  document.querySelector('#perItem').innerHTML = `perItem is now ${perItem}`
})
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Say_M/pen/JjNQMRX)

If anyone wanna help me to add more features in the slider then here is the github link

[slider by Sayem](https://github.com/Say-M/slider/blob/main/slider.js)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `resize` event listener, then loop through `config.breakpoints` to find the corresponding key:

```js
let config = {
  perItem: 4,
  breakpoints: {
    992: {
      perItem: 3
    },
    768: {
      perItem: 2
    }
  }
}
let perItem = config.perItem

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  var keys = Object.keys(config.breakpoints).sort((a, b) => a - b);
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (window.innerWidth < keys[i]) {
      perItem = config.breakpoints[keys[i]].perItem;
      break;
    }
  }
  document.querySelector('#perItem').innerHTML = `perItem is now ${perItem}`
});
```

```html
<div id="perItem">Initial perItem is 4</div>
```

Comment: Here are some mistake you made.
instate of this
`var keys = Object.keys(config.perItem).sort((a, b) => b - a)`
it will be this
`var keys = Object.keys(config.breakpoints).sort((a, b) => b - a)`

(After correction)
but sorry to say that is not working properly.
If I resize the window and
window is less than 992 I get perItem=3 which is correct
window is less than 768 I get perItem=3 which is incorrect (should be perItem=2)
window is greater than 992 I get perItem=3 which is incorrect (should be perItem=4)

[Here is your code](https://codepen.io/Say_M/pen/mdmZqZm?editors=1010)

Comment: Sorry, I had to sort in ascending rather than descending order. It is now fixed, and I added your codepen code as a snippet to demonstrate the effect.